# How to appeared tick when List View item clicked and do not disappeared till the next item clicked also do not disappeared when go to another activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> view3, View view, int view1, long view2) {


        final TextView countid = (TextView) view.findViewById ( R.id.id );
        final TextView count_counting = (TextView) view.findViewById ( R.id.text_view_countiing );
        final TextView any_name = (TextView) view.findViewById ( R.id.textviewname );
        final ImageView deletebutton = (ImageView) view.findViewById ( R.id.deletebutton );

            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation ( getApplicationContext (), R.anim.blinking );
            any_name.setVisibility ( view.VISIBLE );
            any_name.startAnimation ( animation );


            final String realid = countid.getText ().toString ();
            final String realcounting = count_counting.getText ().toString ();
            final String realname = any_name.getText ().toString ();

            Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), MainActivity.class );
            intent.putExtra ( "Id", realid );
            intent.putExtra ( "real_counting", realcounting );
            intent.putExtra ( "real_name", realname );
            startActivity ( intent );
        }

} );
```

Comment: Hey! I am new here if anyone have idea related to my problem plz let me know. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

To make the other views stop being ticked when you click a different one, have your `ListAdapter` store a reference to which one should be ticked, and call `notifyDataSetInvalidated` on it inside the `onItemClicked` function.

To make it persist when you leave the activity:

Make a class variable in your activity that remembers which item should be ticked, and then you can use `onSaveInstanceState` to restore that when you return to the activity.

If you want the state to persist even when the user closes your app and returns, you can save the variable to a `Preferences` object instead.